Maximum likelihood estimator when the Fisher information matrix is not invertible?
It is known that maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) is asymptotically efficient, i.e., $\sqrt{n\,}\,\left( \widehat{\theta \,}_{\mathrm{mle}}-\theta _0 \right) $ converges in distribution to a multivariate normal distribution with mean zero and covariance matrix the inverse of the Fisher information matrix (FIM) $\mathcal{I} $. To wit, we have
$$
\sqrt{n\,}\,\left( \widehat{\theta \,}_{\mathrm{mle}}-\theta _0 \right) \,\, \xrightarrow{d}\,\, \mathcal{N} \left( 0, \mathcal{I} ^{-1} \right) \tag1.
$$
My question is, when the Fisher information matrix is not invertible, do we still have a similar result for the MLE, i.e. eq(1), with the inverse of the FIM replaced by the moore-penrose generalized inverse?

probably depends why is not invertible... if it has negative eigenvalues, you might not have a MLE at all

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273303/singular-fisher-information-matrix-why-is-it-a-problem,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/372553/inverting-hessian-using-generalized-inverse-for-inference,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258640/when-can-i-substitute-an-inverse-with-a-pseudo-inverse-in-an-estimator
